# Error dealing with uninitialized array of pointers C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have five files:  class T, class M (an abstract class), class MC (a container), class AC (creates a particular object that is added into the MC container) and my Main file.
I have these functions to add an object (for this case, AC) and to retrieve a data member that you find in AC (a title).

The program compiles and it appears that I can create and add an AC object. However when I try to use my GetTitle function, the program crashes and I get the following error

> “Unhandled exception at 0x00b938e6 in TLab 5.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0xcccccce4.”

From what I looked up, this means I have a pointer that is bad/uninitialized. The only pointer in my program is this:

```
 M *C[MCSize] //Found in MC.h
```

The constructor for MC looks like this:

```
 MC::MC()
 {
cout << "Enter Name: ";
getline(cin, CName);

cout << "Enter size of collection: ";
cin >> CurrentMCSize;
if (CurrentMCSize < 0 || CurrentMCSize > MCSize)
{
    cout << "Size is invalid. Please re-enter: ";
    cin >> CurrentMCSize;

 }; //MCSize is defined in the header of MC.
```

The function to call the Title that is entered is here:

```
 void MC::ListMTitles()
 {
      for (int i = 0; i < CurrentMCSize; i++)
      {
         cout << i << ". " << Collection[i]->GetTitle();
      }
 };
 //GetTitle is defined in M.cpp
```

Where DMA occurs: //MC.cpp

```
 void MC::AddM()
 {
int Selection;
if(CurrentMCSize < MCSize)
{
    DisplayMTypeMenu();
    Selection = GetMTypeSelection();
    switch(Selection)
    {
    case 1: Collection[CurrentMCSize] = new AC;
    break;
    // Other case statements

    }
    if (0 == Collection[CurrentMCSize])
    {
        cout << "Error: Memory Allocation Failed.";
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "New M Type added!" << endl << endl;
    }
    CurrentMCSize++;
}
```

Have I not properly initialized my pointer? Is my Add function actually lying to me and nothing is being added? I looked around but most answers I saw involved using a vector, which for the sake of this project I don’t think I’m allowed to use as the professor didn’t go over them.

Comment: So it's C++ and not C, right?

Comment: Where does the crash happens?

Comment: You are listing from 0 to `CurrentMCSize`, I believe you havent created those.

Comment: Where are you allocating the array (M *C[MCSize]) itself?

Comment: Should not be `Collection[CurrentMCSize - 1] = new AC` instead of `Collection[CurrentMCSize] = new AC`

Comment: Maybe in your other 'case statements' you're not initializing Collection[CurrentMCSize]?

Comment: You ask for `CurrentMCSize` in constructor. What happens with `Collection[0]` if `CurrentMCSize > 0`? Can you show code where this `MC` container is used? Dou you have proper assignment operator and copy constructor, destructor?

Comment: @RyanMaloney As far as I understand, M *C[MCSize] means an array of pointers to M, not a pointer to array

Comment: Reduce this to a minimal complete example, and I'm sure you'll get a solution in minutes.

Comment: @ H2CO3 - Yes, this C++ not C.
@ Daniel Castro: I'm not sure how to find out exactly where the crash happens. What should I do? Also, the other case statements are currently commented out as they'll be other initialize objects (similar to AC. I'm just working with one right now). And yes, M *C[MCSize] is supposed to be an array of pointers.

Comment: why not use a `std::vector<M*>`?  You still have the overhead of managing the lifetime of your `M` objects, but at least you don't have the trouble of trying to manage your own sparsely populated array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking the user to input the size of the collection during construction, but you never populate those elements of the collection.  Then, when you call `AddM`, it continues from `CurrentMCSize`.  You should instead initialize `CurrentMCSize` to zero in the constructor and not ask for it at all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs because this

```
  for (int i = 0; i < CurrentMCSize; i++)
  {
     cout << i << ". " << Collection[i]->GetTitle();
  }
```

starts at 0 but there is no guarantee that AddM() will begin adding at 0:

```
void MC::AddM()
{
int Selection;
if(CurrentMCSize < MCSize)
{
    DisplayMTypeMenu();
    Selection = GetMTypeSelection();
    switch(Selection)
    {
    case 1: Collection[CurrentMCSize] = new AC;
```

Instead it will add at whatever CurrentMCSize is which could be fed into the constructor as something like 4. You have three separate values you want to track: max supported size, the size presently used and the next slot to allocate an item but you've collapsed the last two into one variable.

Related question - Any reason you don't want to simply use a std::vector and push_back?

Edit: Ah I didn't see it, Paddy beat me to it.

Comment: @ Ryan Maloney and Paddy

Thanks! That helped fix it! I didn't realize the mistake.

As for not using std::vector, like I mentioned, our professor didn't talk about it and I haven't learned much on it yet.